# PHPExcel - chart rendering and load excel giving error

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
require_once('PHPExcel-1.7.7/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$inputFileName = 'RN Tracker.xlsx';

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
```

if i try following

```
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
```

during load i get following error message:

```
Warning: PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007::load(): Node no longer exists in /users/pravkum4/html/tracker/PHPExcel-1.7.7/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 1518

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /users/pravkum4/html/tracker/PHPExcel-1.7.7/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 1519

Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /users/pravkum4/html/tracker/PHPExcel-1.7.7/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 1519
```

What mistake i am doing here?
Should i include some additional class for chart?

Does chart option is included by default in load method of reader? chart count gives 0. :((
Sometimes gives correct chart count but rendering doesn't work.

[image]

One more thing, what is this code? not working for me. Sometimes i get jpgraph_pie.php missing.

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setChartRenderer(
    PHPExcel_Settings::CHART_RENDERER_JPGRAPH,
    dirname(__FILE__).'/../../libraries/Charts/jpgraph3.5.0b1/src'
);
```

Please provide a tutorial for chart rendering. Thank you so much in Advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the correct forum for a request like this. If you encounter a bug with the PHPExcel code, the first place to raise it should be on the PHPExcel discussion forums or the PHPExcel issue list

Comment: Sure Mark, i will give details at correct place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have yet to see this issue raised at the PHPExcel sites on either CodePlex or on Github... and to resolve it you'll need to upload a sample file that demonstrates the problem so that we can identify what node no longer exists in the Excel data

Answer (score 2):

Look at this this may help you...

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/16
- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: It may help - it would have been nice to see a new issue raised rather than a comment against the original request for chart support that was created created 5 years ago, and it would still be nice to see a file uploaded that demonstrates the problem