# PhpExcel - How to display or export a chart already in excel

Tags: phpexcel

I would like to use PHPExcel to save some charts that already exist in an excel file as image files (Save as Image).

Is this possible and can anyone point me to some sample code as Google results only bring back code to generate new charts from numeric data.

Comment: see https://www.google.com/search?q=phpexcel+%22setIncludeCharts%22 , https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/search?q=setIncludeCharts&ref=cmdform , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597769/cant-read-and-write-xlsx-file-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437758/phpexcel-chart-rendering-and-load-excel-giving-error , ...

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the example 35chartrender.php in the /Tests directory, it does exactly what you want. Basically it all comes down to `$chart->render($jpegFileName);`. I don't think there is any way to render a chart as anything else than a jpeg, though you could always ask the expert at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If these are actual images rather than MS Excel charts, then take a look at section 4.6.37 of the developer documentation, entitled "Reading Images from a worksheet":

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                $extension = 'png'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                $extension = 'gif'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                $extension = 'jpg'; break;
        }
    } else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
        $imageContents = '';
        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
    }
    $myFileName = '00_Image_'.++$i.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($myFileName,$imageContents);
}
```

If they are actual MS Excel charts, then (as Technoh has suggested) the chart render() method as demonstrated in example 35chartrender.php will use jpgraph to create an image file from that chart definition.